# Codeigniter set double config upload

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to create multiple config for upload file. This is my code:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './upload/post';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif|jpeg|JPG|PNG|GIF|JPEG';
                $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
                $this->load->library('upload',$config);
                $files = $_FILES;
                $file=$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                $file_array=array();
                for($i=0; $i<1; $i++){
                        $temp = explode(".",$files["userfile"]["name"][$i]);
                        $newfilename = mt_rand() . '.' .end($temp);
                        $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $newfilename;
                        $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
                        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
                        $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
                        $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];
                        $file_array[$i]=$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                        $this->upload->initialize($config);
                        $this->upload->do_upload();
                        $this->upload->data();
                }

                /* second upload file*/
                $config2['upload_path'] = './upload/file';
                $config2['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif|jpeg|JPG|PNG|GIF|JPEG';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config2);
                $file_data = $_FILES;
                $data_file=$_FILES['file_data']['name'];
                $data_array=array();
                for($x=0; $x<1; $x++){
                        $ex = explode(".",$file_data["file_data"]["name"][$x]);
                        $filename = mt_rand() . '.' .end($ex);
                        $_FILES['file_data']['name']= $filename;
                        $_FILES['file_data']['type']= $file_data['file_data']['type'][$x];
                        $_FILES['file_data']['tmp_name']= $file_data['file_data']['tmp_name'][$x];
                        $_FILES['file_data']['error']= $file_data['file_data']['error'][$x];
                        $_FILES['file_data']['size']= $file_data['file_data']['size'][$x];
                        $data_array[$x]=$_FILES['file_data']['name'];
                        $this->upload->initialize($config2);
                        $this->upload->do_upload();
                        $this->upload->data();
                }
                /*end upload file script*/
```

How i can set multiple config? Is that possible?

Do you have another way to upload multiple file with different name file tag?

Answer (score 0):

You are currently just overwriting the same configuration. You need to create an array of upload configurations. Like this:

```
$config['upload_configs'] = array();
$config['upload_configs'][0]['upload_path'] = './upload/post';
$config['upload_configs'][1]['upload_path'] = './upload/file';
....
```

Comment: what is ['upload_configs'] ? can I change that with another like ['upload_data'] ? and how to initialize config and load library ?

Comment: You can name it what you like. You can use the autoloader to load as many config files as you want.

Comment: can you give me some example code? because i try that and not work.